# Expected value of the inverse of a random variable

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable. $X$ can take the value 1 with probability $p$, and the value 2 with probability $1-p$.

Can we write $E[\frac{1}{X}] = \frac{1}{E[X]}$?
(note that $E[X] \neq 0$)

Thank you in advance for any clarification.

Comment: Your question, rewritten using the definition of expectation, asks "Can we write $p\times (1/1) + (1-p)\times (1/2) = 1/(p\times 1 + (1-p)\times 2)$?"  Why not check this out for one or two values of $p$ and see? Try $p=1/2$ for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The answer is well known [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Generally, $E[f(x)]\ne f(E[X])$.

However, it may hold for some functions and some probability distributions. For instance, for linear functions such as $f(x)=a+bx$ it holds that $E[f(x)]= f(E[X])$.

Also, you can find $p$ for which this is true in your example (i.e. a specific probability distribution).

$E[x]=p+2(1-p)=2-p$,

$E[f(x)]=p+(1-p)/2=(1+p)/2$

Hence, for $p=1$ or $p=0$, the equality holds.
Credit to whuber for a comment.

Comment: (+1) $p=0$ is also a solution. (There are no others.) The assertion about "only for linear functions" is true when accompanied by the right quantifier: you must demand that $E[f(x)] = f(E[X])$ for a large number of random variables. For instance, $f(x) = (3+\cos(\pi x))/2$ works *for this particular* set of $X$ given in the question, even though $f$ is not linear.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your answers and comments!